# Log timestamp of an exception in Play?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework

I have some play code that calls some spark functions. Sometimes things break and I want a timestamp associated to the event. I currently get the error messages printed to STDOUT without a timestamp and am wondering if there's a way to configure the logger.xml to associate timestamps with these??

Comment: Read your logger configuration documentation for that. In Play the default is Logback, so if you didn't override that this page http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html may be useful.

Comment: Play 2's default logger adds a timestamp to every log event. How are you even missing that ? Is it PlayFramework 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Providing your logger.xml file would have been helpful but anyways look for the "pattern" element for your STDOUT in the logger.xml file and change it by  prepending the **%d{ISO8601}**

Check the logback configuration documentation for more information.

[Logback Configuration](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)